# SQL Query for vendors who have sold item more than once

Tags: sql

I need help with the following query...Show the names of vendors who have sold us an item more than once.  List the vendor, item, and the number of times ordered.  Suppose a vendor sold 8 of item 240 on Dec 1 and 12 of item 240 on Dec 30; this counts as two total orders of item 240 (not 20). The tables are ...

> ```
> employee (empid, firstname, middleinitial, lastname, address)
> parts (partnum, description)
> payments (checknum, checkdate, vendorid, ponum, accountnum, amount)
> poitems (ponum, partnum, quantity, unitprice)
> purchaseorder (ponum, podate, vendorid, empid, amount)
> vendor (vendorid, name, address, phone, tin)
> ```

Comment: Other people are asking very similar questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114924/sql-query-formation-question. Is this some kind of homework? If so, please add the homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT vendor.name, partnum, COUNT (DISTINCT ponum) AS times_ordered
FROM purchaseorder
JOIN vendor USING (vendorid)
JOIN poitems USING (ponum)
GROUP BY vendorid, partnum
HAVING times_ordered > 1
```

Comment: Oh, maybe it's MySQL dialect. USING(col) means ON (table1.col = table2.col)

Comment: I checked it, it's standard SQL, so MS SQL should support it.