# Sliding window minimum algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sliding-window

This is a homework problem. Let A[] is an array of integers and integer K -- window size. Generate array M of minimums seen in a window as it slides over A. I found [an article](http://home.tiac.net/~cri/2001/slidingmin.html) with a solution for this problem but did not understand **why** it has O(n) complexity. Can anybody explain it to me?

Comment: @Andre: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. Saw it requested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114917/sql-query-for-vendors-who-have-sold-item-more-than-once. Maybe there should be a note in the tag's description?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This tends to catch people out. You would think it would take `O(N^2)` time since you reason adding takes `O(N)` time and you have `O(N)` elements. However, realise each element can only be added once and removed once. So in total it takes `O(N)` to slide over the whole array `A`.

This yields an amortised efficiency of `O(1)` every time you move the sliding window on by one element. In other words, the average time it takes to move the sliding window by one element is `O(1)`.